# Bind 9.9.11 compile error on Solaris 11.3

Tags: compilation, bind, solaris

An error occurred When I compile bind 9.9.11 on Solaris 11, 
How fix it? thanks.

**SunOS sunflower 5.11 11.3 i86pc i386 i86pc, CPU_2017-10**

**gcc version 4.5.2**

Configure:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/bind9 \
--sysconfdir=/etc \
--libdir=/usr/lib/dns \
--with-openssl \
--with-libtool \
--enable-threads \
--enable-devpoll=yes \
--enable-largefile \
--disable-openssl-version-check \
--enable-fixed-rrset \
--with-libxml2=/usr
```

configure error:

```
checking if unistd.h or sys/types.h defines fd_set... yes
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for OpenSSL library... using OpenSSL from /usr/lib and /usr/include
checking whether linking with OpenSSL works... yes
checking whether linking with OpenSSL requires -ldl... no
Skipped OpenSSL version check
checking for OpenSSL DSA support... yes
checking for EVP_sha256... yes
checking for EVP_sha384... yes
checking for EVP_sha512... yes
checking for OpenSSL ECDSA support... yes
checking for OpenSSL GOST support... no
checking for PKCS11 support... disabled
checking for PKCS11 tools... disabled
checking for GSSAPI library... looking in /usr/lib
checking gssapi.h usability... no
checking gssapi.h presence... no
checking for gssapi.h... no
checking gssapi/gssapi.h usability... yes
checking gssapi/gssapi.h presence... yes
checking for gssapi/gssapi.h... yes
checking gssapi_krb5.h usability... no
checking gssapi_krb5.h presence... no
checking for gssapi_krb5.h... no
checking gssapi/gssapi_krb5.h usability... no
checking gssapi/gssapi_krb5.h presence... no
checking for gssapi/gssapi_krb5.h... no
checking krb5.h usability... no
checking krb5.h presence... no
checking for krb5.h... no
checking krb5/krb5.h usability... no
checking krb5/krb5.h presence... no
checking for krb5/krb5.h... no
checking kerberosv5/krb5.h usability... no
checking kerberosv5/krb5.h presence... no
checking for kerberosv5/krb5.h... no
configure: error: krb5.h not found
```

However, krb5.h is in the directory below：

/usr/include/kerberosv5/krb5.h

/usr/include/kerberosv5/krb5/krb5.h

**The config.log file some information:**

```
...
| #define ISC_SOCKADDR_LEN_T socklen_t
| #define TIME_WITH_SYS_TIME 1
| #define HAVE_UNAME 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_DEVPOLL_H 1
| #define HAVE_DEVPOLL_H 1
| #define HAVE_OPENSSL_DSA 1
| #define HAVE_EVP_SHA256 1
| #define HAVE_EVP_SHA384 1
| #define HAVE_EVP_SHA512 1
| #define HAVE_OPENSSL_ECDSA 1
| #define HAVE_GSSAPI_GSSAPI_H 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <kerberosv5/krb5.h>
configure:14474: result: no
configure:14474: checking for kerberosv5/krb5.h
configure:14474: result: no
configure:14487: error: krb5.h not found

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=i386-pc-solaris2.11
ac_cv_c_bigendian=no
...
...
#define HAVE_SYS_PARAM_H 1
#define FLEXIBLE_ARRAY_MEMBER /**/
#define HAVE_SETEUID 1
#define HAVE_SETEGID 1
#define HAVE_FTELLO 1
#define HAVE_FSEEKO 1
#define ISC_SOCKADDR_LEN_T socklen_t
#define TIME_WITH_SYS_TIME 1
#define HAVE_UNAME 1
#define HAVE_SYS_DEVPOLL_H 1
#define HAVE_DEVPOLL_H 1
#define HAVE_OPENSSL_DSA 1
#define HAVE_EVP_SHA256 1
#define HAVE_EVP_SHA384 1
#define HAVE_EVP_SHA512 1
#define HAVE_OPENSSL_ECDSA 1
#define HAVE_GSSAPI_GSSAPI_H 1

configure: exit 1
```

Comment: Have you checked config.log to see why it says `kerberosv5/krb5.h` failed the checks?

Comment: Yes, I have checked. But  install it on solaris 10 no this problem.